# SlowMode for one person is possible ? discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I would like to know if it is possible to do some sort of "SlowMode" for a specific person on Discord.

The reason is that I have a "spammer" friend, and I would like to calm him down with a command that might slow him down when he speaks for "x" secondes.

So I would like to know if this is possible? and if yes, how?

Thank you for your kindness =) (and sorry for this english i use GoogleTraductor)

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I can tell you the English expression you are looking for is probably "rate limiting".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I'd do that.

```js
let ratelimits = [];

client.on("message", (msg) => {
    // APPLYING RATELIMITS
    const appliedRatelimit = ratelimits.find(
        (value) =>
            value.user === msg.author.id && value.channel === msg.channel.id
    );
    if (appliedRatelimit) {
        // Can they post the message?
        const canPostMessage =
            msg.createdAt.getTime() - appliedRatelimit.ratelimit >=
            appliedRatelimit.lastMessage;

        // They can
        if (canPostMessage)
            return (ratelimits[
                ratelimits.indexOf(appliedRatelimit)
            ].lastMessage = msg.createdAt.getTime());

        // They can't
        msg.delete({ reason: "Enforcing ratelimit." });
    }

    // SET RATELIMIT
    if (msg.content === "!ratelimit") {
        // Checking it's you
        if (msg.author.id !== "your id") return msg.reply("You can't do that.");

        // You can change these values in function of the received message
        const targetedUserId = "whatever id you want";
        const targetedChannelId = msg.channel.id;
        const msRateLimit = 2000; // 2 seconds

        // Delete existant ratelimit if any for this user on this channel
        ratelimits = ratelimits.filter(
            (value) =>
                !(
                    value.user === targetedUserId &&
                    value.channel === targetedChannelId
                )
        );

        // Add ratelimit
        ratelimits.push({
            user: targetedUserId,
            channel: targetedChannelId,
            ratelimit: msRateLimit,
            lastMessage: 0,
        });
    }

    // CLEAR RATELIMITS
    if (msg.content === "!clearRatelimits") {
        // Checking it's you
        if (msg.author.id !== "your id") return msg.reply("You can't do that.");
        // Clearing all ratelimits
        ratelimits = [];
    }
});
```

Comment: Hello I wanted to thank you very much for the help you just gave me, but I have a little problem with the code you sent me when I run the BOT it works but when I execute the command "! Ratelimit "they tell me: Uncaught ReferenceError: msRateLimit is not defined. Could you if you want, tell how to fix the cause of this error please.

Comment: Okay i just add a capital letter to msRateLimit and that works THANK YOU VERY MUCH